# Как при помощи JS определить, рабочая ссылка на файл или нет?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. 
Как при помощи `JavaScript` определить, ссылка на картинку рабочая или нет?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пишешь файл test_link.php, в котором curl'ом проверяешь, работает ли ссылка. Далее ,в js делаешь запрос на test_link.php через ajax. Получаешь результат, радуешься :) С помощью чистого js никак такого не сделаешь.

Comment: ок, спасибо. А вам не тяжело привести этот код PHP. Просто я с ним не работаю, и близко не знаю никаких принципов его работы. Т.е. просто, чтобы от начала до конца, можно было бы закопипастить и заработало.

Comment: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2007/08/02/how-to-check-if-page-exists-with-curl/

Вот тут пример такой фукнции. Просто создайте файл check_page.php, внутрь добавьте:

<?php
function page_exists($url){
// тут код функции из примера
}

if (page_exists($_POST['url'])) echo "1"; else echo "0";
?>

Как-то так, и далее, при вызове этой страницы с POST параметром url=адрес_страницы в случае существования адреса страницы будет возвращена 1, в случае отсутствия  - 0. Ну а дальше уже со стороны js проверяешь, что там ajax вызов вернул.

Answer (score 4):

Например, на [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/error/):

```
$(function(){ //On DOM ready
    $('#img').error(function(){
        alert('error');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<img src="fafav.jpg" id="img" />
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/KGM5N/1/)

Comment: Будет работать только в пределах домена.

PS. Хотя нет, работает и с кроссдоменными заросами. Но тут минус - только картинки можно проверять.

Comment: >Как при помощи JavaScript определить, ссылка на картинку рабочая или нет?
В констексте задачи минуса нет.
Плюсы очевидны: не нужно писать лишний сервер-сайд код, обрабатывать ajax-запросы.

Comment: Хм. Мне достаточно только картинки. А как это будет выглядеть без использования библиотек?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NHvF6/

Comment: Сработало!

Answer (score 1):

Для ссылок в пределах одного домена:

```
function TestURL(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('HEAD', url, false);
    request.send();

    return request.status != 404;
}
```