# Узнать изображение по ссылке

Tags: изображения, javascript

Всем привет! Хочу реализовать такую вот фишку:

Есть input, у которого на событие `onkeypress` должно проверяться: ссылка ли эта на рабочее изображение? Но как это можно реализовать? Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Повторяете вопрос: [Как при помощи JS определить, рабочая ссылка на файл или нет?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/83137/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D0%B8-js-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82)

Comment: Спасибо, не видел.